# Updating HTML data-attributes of a loading-bar in REACT

Tags: reactjs, custom-data-attribute

I am using **Loading.io** library to create a loading bar and update it whenever a user enters a number. I am using React to achieve this. I set user input as my app state and passing them as props across components.

I have a component LoadingBar_Update to update the LoadingBar component whenever new prop is being passed.

```
  Parent.js
  class ParentComp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
  this.state = { reading: "45" };
 }
 onInputChange(event) {
this.setState({ reading: event.target.value });
 } 
  render() {
   return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <input type="text" onChange={event => this.onInputChange(event)} />
    <h2>{this.state.reading}</h2>
    <LoadingBar reading={this.state.reading}/>
  </React.Fragment>
   );
 } 
} 

    LoadingBar.js
     const LoadingBar = props => {
     return <div className="ldBar" data-value={props.reading} data-preset="fan" 
     />;
     };
```

The problem is Loading Component is not re rendering and Loading bar is always stuck on initial state value. I am able to update the data-attributes when I inspect through React dev tools but it is not re rendering. Please point me out where I am doing wrong.

Thank you

Comment: May be one comment help someone, i found out ReactJs ***doesnt rerenders*** and ***update*** the component's html attributes if you changed them only in a store (f.e. redux). This means you push the changes to the store of **aria/data** attributes, but nothing else is changed (such as component's content or class or variables in there) as the result ReactJs will not update **aria/data**  attrs in that components. 
I've been messing around about whole day to realise that.

Answer (score 0):

For loading bar you need to update data using [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) because according to the docs. state thing wont work loading bar wont update on data update it is having set method for that so you need to use that method for updating component and for calling set method u need dom object that u can get it by refs(react way for dom objects). hope this will help.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {}
  onInputChange = e => {
    this.loadbarRef.ldBar.set(e.target.value);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.onInputChange} />
        <div
          className="ldBar"
          data-value={20}
          data-preset="fan"
          ref={t => (this.loadbarRef = t)}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi, I did like you said  changed my code still same issue. Did you mean I need to use setState in Loadbar.js to make it re render?

Comment: how you are calling readingUpdate function means when your reading is getting changed???

Comment: just check i have update parent comp and remove your other LoadingBar.js and we don't need UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps as well just use what i have given. no other component breakups

Comment: Hi I did like you said still nothing is going on. data-value does change but loading bar doesn't change  remains same. Do I need to use bind if I am using arrow function? It's giving me error for using bind(this). Thank you

Comment: and bar is not updating that may be that package is not adapting directly updated dom i will try with that package and let you know